# ¿Es pertinente traducir la pregunta canónica "¿Cómo puedo sustituir una cadena en un fichero?" en una sola pregunta?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, revisión-de-pregunta, traducciones-de-contenido

En Unix & Linux existe la pregunta canónica [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112023/40596) que acumula más de un millón de visitas por lo común que es lo que pide: **¿Cómo puedo sustituir una cadena en uno o muchos ficheros?**.

La pregunta se creó con la voluntad de ser completa y extensa, cubriendo todas las posibles casuísticas: distintos patrones, uno o más ficheros, hacerlo recursivamente, utilizar distintos reemplazos, etc.

A mí me gusta la pregunta así como está, pues también resulta un atractor de duplicados en pos de una pregunta canónica, en lugar de tener el conocimiento desperdigado. Sin embargo, también observo que es fácil que su contenido sea algo extenso y pierda la claridad. No es comprimible porque ya contiene lo mínimo indispensable, pero es larga.

Me apetece traducirla, igual que hice con [¿Cómo puedo seleccionar las líneas entre dos patrones?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/55221/83), pero antes me gustaría consultar: ¿la plantea como una o muchas preguntas distintas?

A favor de una sola:

- Atractor de muchos duplicados presentes y futuros.
- Canónica y cubriendo todas las casuísticas.
- Casos entremedios son fáciles de cubrir.

A favor de muchas:

- Más concisa.
- Que no me cierren una única por "demasiado amplia" :)

---

Finalmente la formulé en [¿Cómo puedo sustituir una cadena en uno o muchos ficheros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/187445/83) y la puse en modo Wiki para animar a que se mejore colaborativamente, tal y ocmo se hizo en su origen en Unix & Linux.

Comment: Yo estoy a favor de una sola. Con las preguntas canónicas soy partidario de tener "manga ancha" respecto a que sean demasiado amplias, ya que al atraer numerosos duplicados ayudan a la "limpieza" del sitio. De hecho, una que traduje yo [Que es una nullreferenceexception](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75999/15301) es incluso mas extensa y fue muy bien recibida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para mí, estás diciendo todo con

> A mí me gusta la pregunta así como está

Creo que conviene mantenerle eso que te gusta (-y que a mí también) y no despedazarla en partes.

Si fuese una nueva pregunta sin respuesta, sería demasiado amplia, pero al ser contenido que estarías compartiendo como pregunta-respuesta, creo que tenemos el suficiente criterio para entender que es un excelente contenido y que vale la pena mantenerlo. Y además tampoco es tanto como un capítulo de un libro. Para mí tiene el balance perfecto entre utilidad y no ser tan extensa.

La idea de SOes es aportar contenido de calidad. ¿Por qué no apuntar a seguir subiendo la vara?

El hecho de que ayude a limpiar el sitio con duplicados también es algo positivo. Yo le veo todo a favor y nada en contra. Y sos uno de los principales usuarios de SOes en esas etiquetas, yo confío en tu criterio para orientarlas por el mejor camino.